# Defining multiple states in Angular in one line, using UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Apologies if this question is obvious.

I am defining several states simultaneously in my main modules file for use with UI-Router.

My code is:

```
 samApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: "",
      views: {
        "nav": {template: "index.nav"},
        "header": { template: "index.viewA" },
        "page": { template: "index.viewB" }
      }
    })
    .state('articles', {
      url: "/route1",
      views: {
        "nav": {template: "index.nav"},
        "viewA": { template: "route1.viewA" },
        "viewB": { template: "route1.viewB" }
      }
    })
    .state('route2', {
      url: "/route2",
      views: {
        "nav": {template: "index.nav"},
        "viewA": { template: "route2.viewA" },
        "viewB": { template: "route2.viewB" }
      }
    })
});
```

As you can see, I want every route to use the same Nav. Would it be possible to write something like:

```
.state(['index', 'articles', 'route2'], {
      url: "",
      views: {
        "nav": {template: "index.nav"}
      }
    })
```

Or is this just out of the question?
Thank you.

Comment: seems like you only need the `otherwise` method. Every route will bring you back to the one that `otherwise` redirects you to.

Comment: @JoeMinichino I thought otherwise sets a state for non-referenced routes. I am referencing the three states I enclosed in the bracketed portion at the bottom. I just want to include a view for every state, including them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to group view definition, use an abstract state:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        // use quotes for avoiding compilation issues with this reserved word
        'abstract': true,
        url: '',
        views: {
            'nav': { template: 'index.nav' }
        }
    })
    .state('articles', {
        parent: 'parent',
        url: "/route1",
        views: {
            // use the viewName@stateName syntax (stateName is empty since we address root no name state
            "header@": { template: "index.viewA" },
            "page@": { template: "index.viewB" }
        }
    })
    /* ... quite the same for other child states */
;
```

See [ui router view names documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) and [ui router abstract state documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-states).
            '

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense!